# Access the AllUsers selection with an MSI CustomAction

Tags: c#, windows-installer, custom-action

I'm having a heck of time figuring out how to access the AllUsers selection from within a custom action.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else is fighting with this issueit's spelled out pretty well on this thread:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformssetup/thread/e3226d5c-a0f6-41be-b707-483cb6b0901b/